# create Debian package without bin dir

Tags: debian, make, deb

deb package with structure (project (bin(source)) DEBIAN(control)) can be created

But want to create deb package without bin directory instead there multiple directories and source file inside project, can't change files location.

Can i make modification so it wouldn't look for bin folder instead check all files and directories for deb package creation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if file is out of the bin folder but inside the package folder.. it can be packed and used as it is. For the execution of X file use. bin/../pathtofile instead of direct ./file